# React Native-Update a property of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Have an array of objects and want to update only the stock property of the object with an `increaseQuantity()` function. how can I go about that?

```
    increaseQuantity = (id) => {
    let newData = this.state.data.map(obj => {
        if (obj.id === id) {
            //Block of Code
        }
        return obj
    })
    this.setState({ newData })

    console.log(newData)
}
```

sample data are as follows:

```
    const Items = [
{ id: '0', text: 'Alvaro Beer', stock: 500 },
{ id: '1', text: 'Malta Guinnesse', stock: 200 }
```

Render Element :

```
    <FlatList
                        data={Items}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                            <Products
                                id={item.id}
                                text={item.text}
                                price={item.price}
                                stock={item.stock}
                                onSwipeIncrease={() => this.increaseQuantity()}
                                onSwipeDecrease={() => console.log('Sub')}
                                onSwipeAddToCart={() => console.log('Cart')}
                            />
                        )}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this simple solution

```
increaseQuantity = id => {
  let updateItems = [...this.state.items];
  // get the index according to id
  let index = this.state.items.findIndex(obj => obj.id == id);
  // check whether passed id exits in the items
  if (!!index) {
    // suppose you want to change stock value to 2000
    updateItems[index].stock = 2000;
    this.setState({
      items: updateItems
    });
  }
};
```

In order to do that your `state` should like this

```
state = {
  items: [
    { id: "0", text: "Alvaro Beer", stock: 500 },
    { id: "1", text: "Malta Guinnesse", stock: 200 }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: want to increase the value of stock with the press of a button

Comment: @Dvyne you can achieve that using the above code. if you want then you pass the value as well & you need to handle that inside ```increaseQuantity```

Comment: @Dvyne only thing which you have do is replace ```updateItems[index].stock = <your_value>;``` with your value.

Comment: getting `type error: undefined is not an object` for `updateItems[index].stock = 2000;`

Comment: @Dvyne did you replace your ```increaseQuantity``` function with above code?

Comment: Yh I did replace it.

Comment: ```type error: undefined is not an object``` happen because you are passing an ```id``` which not available in your ```state``` so it returns ```undefined```. try passing value ```0``` or ```1``` to ```increaseQuantity```

Comment: @Dvyne I change my answer to handle ```undefined``` values.

Comment: I am using flatlist to render the objects, so `increaseQuantity` is passed to each object dynamically

Comment: @Dvyne I update my answer if you have any doubts update your question then I might be able to help you.

Comment: @Dvyne you need to pass id to ```increaseQuantity``` as below ```onSwipeIncrease={() => this.increaseQuantity(item.id)}```

Comment: did that and it only updates the second object if clicked

Comment: hm, that's wired. try place ```console.log()``` inside your ```increaseQuantity``` & check passed value